# is EXPUNGE allowed in IMAP APPEND command

Tags: append, imap, rfc

Is this an allowed "response" to an IMAP APPEND command? Sometimes the mailserver where I want to upload some messages responds this way and my current implementation does to allow the EXPUNGE.

```
A00003 APPEND "somefolder" (\Seen) "12-Dec-2012 12:12:12 +0000" {1212}
* 1 EXPUNGE
* 18 EXISTS
* 18 RECENT
+ send APPEND data...
```

What I have:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.4.1

> An EXPUNGE response MUST NOT be sent when no command is in progress,
> nor while responding to a FETCH, STORE, or SEARCH command.

Also:

> A command is not "in progress" until the complete command
> has been received; in particular, a command is not "in progress"
> during the negotiation of command continuation.

I am not able to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is behaving incorrectly. It should not send `EXPUNGE` and then the `+` continuation. That said, this rule

```
in particular, a command is not "in progress" during the
negotiation of command continuation
```

is a bit little senseless and I would not trust random servers to obey it.

I can guess why the rule exists. In a command like the one below, the meaning of `3:7` depends on which `EXPUNGE` responses the client has parsed and acted on before it constructed the string `3:7`:

```
a uid search subject {3}
foo
3:7
```

But the server has to deal with MSNs. Clients can generally choose to avoid the whole problem area by using UIDs instead of MSNs.

My suggestion is to avoid sending MSNs, to use UIDs always, and to be as tolerant as you can of oddly timed `EXPUNGE` responses.

Comment: I would agree, this an EXPUNGE is technically against specification.

Comment: @Max: Your comment is technically against the English grammar specification. SCNR.

Comment: :). All sorts of weird things creep in when using smartphone keyboards to reply.

Comment: You are saying "it should not". In RFC speak this means it is not forbidden, therefore there server is not behaving incorrectly. "The server is behaving incorrectly. It should not send EXPUNGE and then the + continuation.", which paragraphs are you referring to?

Comment: The RFC instelf says MUST NOT. Also, SHOULD NOT in RFCs also means forbidden in practice. SHOULD NOT allows exceptions "in particular circumstances, but the full implications should be understood and carefully weighed". The author of that rule meant it for "oh no, we have file system damage here, we can't honour our promises!", not for "eh, I don't like that rule".

Comment: @Lars: I think you should reread RFC 2119. You seem to confuse SHOULD with MAY.